# Is there any way to rename or hide only one HTML tag?

Tags: php, jquery, html, tags, hide

**Preface:** I cannot rename the source tags or edit their IDs. Any changes to the tags must happen after they have been fetched.

**What I'm doing:** using file_get_contents in PHP, I am requesting data from a remote site. This data is just two `<p>` tags. I need to hide or rename the second of the two `<p>` tags.
Is this possible with PHP or jQuery?

**What I'm working with:**

```
<p>Hello my name is test</p><p>I like studying geology.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to hide second text, you can do this with Jquery:

```
$('p:eq(1)').hide();
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mg624/)

Answer (score 1):

You could try a php string replace

```
 $new_string = str_replace('</p><p>','',file_get_contents('somecontent'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it before render HTML, you need to parse contents and remove/replace second p tag and create a new content.

Here is a DOM parser [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
Find similar questions below 
[How to match second <a> tag in this string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689038/how-to-match-second-a-tag-in-this-string)
[How to add attribute to first P tag using PHP regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216558/how-to-add-attribute-to-first-p-tag-using-php-regular-expression)

Or you can do it after rendering HTML as rNix suggested.